# Pytest: Test a method with different global variable

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I am writing pytest for a script where the method is using the global variable. While writing a test method for the script, I want to pass the DUMMY global variable(i.e. 2) to it instead of the original value(i.e. 55). So I wrote a script (can see below), but that resulted my failure.

```
# script1.py

VAL = 55
def add_one():
   return VAL+1
```

Pytest script for the above script:

```
# test_script1.py

import pytest
from script1 import add_one

DUMMY_VAL = 2

@pytest.mark.parametrize("VAL", DUMMY_VAL)
def test_add_one():
    expected_output = 3
    observed_output = add_one()
    assert observed_output == expected_output
```

But the above test script is **Failing** as it is taking the VAL to be `55` instead of `2`. So my question is, is there a way by which I can pass `DUMMY_VAL` to the test method so as to pass my test case.
Also, one condition: I do not wish to change my method definition in the `script.py` file.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble you are having are all signs telling you not to use globals. Especially since you are using the language of function parameters (i.e. *s there a way by which I can **pass** DUMMY_VAL*).

Having said that, you *can* patch the variable with something like — you just need to do the imports in a way that you can access the imported module:

```
from unittest.mock import patch
import script1

DUMMY_VAL = 2


@patch('script1.VAL', DUMMY_VAL)
def test_add_one():
    expected_output = 3
    observed_output = script1.add_one()
    assert observed_output == expected_output
```

Comment: Is there a way by which I can patch like `add_one.VAL`?

Comment: Not that I know of @tokesh, `VAL` is not a property of `add_one`.